# Acroread deamon

Tags: adobe-reader

I have installed the Adobe Reader and it works fine. But whenever I start Ubuntu there will also start a process called acroread. This process probably enhances the speed if you open the Adobe Reader. But to me it is a waste of recourses.

I know I could kill that process, but does anyone know an elegant way to prohibit this process to start?

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

*Warning:* This could not be a daemon, but an application started in your "startup applications" so look there first!  (via the dash)

If not, to remove any daemon from the start-up process do:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f daemon-name remove
```

I don't have the Acroread daemon, so to get the exact name do:

```
ls /etc/init.d
```

and look for the name there...